# How to show a dropdown inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a project where I have a list of details.
I need to give a dropdown option on Delete button click. I have tried it but unable to show the dropdown inside ng-repeat. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this.

I want to show a dropdown list when I click on delete button.

Below is the code which I tried with no result:

```html
<i class="fa fa-download tooltipped dropdown-button" data-activates='deleteList{{u.$index}}' data-position="top" data-tooltip="Downloads" aria-hidden="true" tooltip-loader></i>

<ul id='deleteList{{u.$index}}' class='dropdown-content' style="">

  <li><a ng-click="deleteAll();">Delete all</a>
  </li>
  <li><a ng-click="deleteSelected();">Delete only selected</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charms/eP7T8/61/)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle..?

Comment: oops.. sorry. i missed it

Comment: I want to show a dropdown list when I click on delete button.

Comment: That is clear from question. Question is is it static list or is it dependent on user's entry?

Comment: That should be static I want to show only two options in each list.  1) Delete all. 2) Delete only selected.

Comment: it can be achieved with ng-show or ng-hide

Comment: Can you please show it @chirag

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/eP7T8/114/ ?

Answer (score 1):

i have created demo for dropdown:

**html:**

```
<button ng-model="show" ng-click="show=!show">
delete
</button>
<ul ng-show="show">
<li>Delete all</li>
<li>Delete only selected</li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid #a6a6a6;
  width:150px;
}
li{
  list-style-type:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
li:hover{
  background-color:#b3b3b3;
}
```

And here is jsfiddle: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/exf72nmq/)

**Dropdown in ng-repeat:**

And here is complete solution in your jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/eP7T8/116/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @chirag. Can you show it in ng-repeat. that is in my fiddle. if it works the I wud like to accept your answer.

Comment: Any way I got the solution Thanks for answering. +1 :)

Comment: here is what you want: in your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eP7T8/115/

Comment: Once I select any of the option that dropdown should hide right?

Comment: yup it should hide. and it can be achieved with ng-click event on li tag

Comment: Yes that will be perfect but when I click on the second delete button first delete option must hide automatically right?

Comment: yup it should hide. and these things are your requirement that how you want to design

Comment: Yes But Iam not getting it in the above example.

Comment: i updated my answer.i hope this will help you. here is what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/eP7T8/116/

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution, I hope this is what you're looking for

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }
    ];
    
    vm.deleteItem = deleteItem;
    
    function deleteItem(option, itemId) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(option);
      console.log(itemId);
    }
  }
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
        <button ng-click="item.delete = true">Delete</button>
        <select ng-show="item.delete" ng-options="option for option in ['Delete All', 'Delete Selected']" ng-model="ctrl.deleteOption" ng-change="ctrl.deleteItem(ctrl.deleteOption, item.id)">
          <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any way I got the solution Thanks for answering. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UI-Bootstrap in your application then use UIB Dropdowns.

Script and HTML will go like this:

```js
  $scope.status = {
    isopen: false
  };
  
  $scope.options = [{
    name: "Delete Selected"
  },
  {
    name: "Delete All"
  }];
  
  $scope.delete = function(name){
    alert(name);
  }
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
    Delete <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li ng-repeat="op in options" role="menuitem" ng-click="delete(op.name)"><a href="#">{{op.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also I've modified angular's UIB Dropdown plunker. you can check it here:
[Dropdown Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rnt85IOiSEAKaytA0vhM?p=preview)